# How to show $(\mathbb{Z} /12\mathbb{Z})^\times $ is isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove
\begin{align}
(\mathbb{Z} /12\mathbb{Z})^\times  \simeq C_2\times C_2
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
(\mathbb{Z} /12\mathbb{Z})^\times  = \{ \bar{a} \in \mathbb{Z} /12\mathbb{Z} \mid \gcd(a,12)=1\} = \{ \bar{1}, \bar{5}, \bar{7}, \bar{11}\}
\end{align}
and $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$.

Comment: With such a small case, you can simply write down an explicit isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use the *Chinese remainder theorem*:
$$\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z \simeq\mathbf Z /4\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z, \enspace\text{therefore }\quad (\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z)^\times \simeq(\mathbf Z /4\mathbf Z)^\times \times(\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z)^\times$$
Now $\;(\mathbf Z /4\mathbf Z)^\times\simeq\dotsm\;$ and $\;(\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z)^\times\simeq\dotsm$

Comment: Thanks, i see now i got the answer